# передача картинки во ViewPager

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api

помогите передать картинку из ВК в ViewPager....

Передаю так:

```
ArrayList<String> imgUrls1 = new ArrayList<>();
imgUrls1.add(vkPhoto.photo_604);

protected void onItemImageClick(Context context, int position, List<String> list) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, FullPhoto.class);
                intent.putStringArrayListExtra(Constants.BUNDLE_BITMAP, imgUrls1);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        };
```

и достаю так:

```
    public class FullPhoto extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager mPager;
    private PagerAdapter mAdapter;
    Context сontext;
    ArrayList<String> ar1;
    private TextView tv_photo_number;
    private int mCurrentPhoto;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_photo);

        ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
        bar.hide();

        tv_photo_number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_photo_number);

        ar1 = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList(Constants.BUNDLE_BITMAP);

        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mAdapter = new FullPhotoPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                setFormattedPageInfo(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            }
        });
        mPager.setCurrentItem(mCurrentPhoto);
        if (mCurrentPhoto == 0) {
            setFormattedPageInfo(mCurrentPhoto);
        }
    }

    private class FullPhotoPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public FullPhotoPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return FullPhotoFragment.newInstance(position, ar1.get(position), ar1.size());
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return ar1.size();
        }
    }

    private void setFormattedPageInfo(int position) {
        String pageInfo = String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.photo_number),
                position + 1, ar1.size());
        tv_photo_number.setText(pageInfo);
    }
}
```

========================

```
public class FullPhotoFragment extends Fragment {

    private String mUrl;
    private Context context;

    public static FullPhotoFragment newInstance(int page, String url, int pageCount) {
        FullPhotoFragment fragment = new FullPhotoFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        args.putString(Constants.BUNDLE_BITMAP, url);

        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args != null) {
            mUrl = args.getString(Constants.BUNDLE_BITMAP);
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_full_photo, container, false);

        ImageView iv_full_photo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_full_photo);
        Picasso.with(context).load(mUrl).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_ab_app).into(iv_full_photo);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Проблема в том что открываются картинки co смещением на новостях.....

Comment: вы не показали, как же они "открываются", и что значит "какие хотят"?

Comment: если дебажить, то ar1 = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList(Constants.BUNDLE_BITMAP); уже изначально приходит со смещением на одну статью....